# Remove specific file from cmake build

Tags: cmake

I have a project in which i have essentially two main methods. One for testing and one for, well, running the code. 
Normally you would create submodules, but this is not an option.

```
file(GLOB sources "*.cpp")
file(GLOB headers "*.h")
add_executable(testing ${sources} ${headers})   
add_executable(main ${sources} ${headers})
```

So testing should compile all sources except for main.cpp.
Main should compile everything but testing.cpp.

Comment: Also see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70802967/779419

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The normal way would probably be to create a library from all the sources except main.cpp and testing.cpp, then link this to each executable.  However, I guess you mean you can't do that when you say you can't create submodules.

Instead, you can use the [`list(REMOVE_ITEM ...)`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command:list) command:

```
file(GLOB sources "*.cpp")
file(GLOB headers "*.h")
set(testing_sources ${sources})
list(REMOVE_ITEM testing_sources ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp)
list(REMOVE_ITEM sources ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/testing.cpp)
add_executable(main ${sources} ${headers})
add_executable(testing ${testing_sources} ${headers})
```

Comment: Does this work? 'Cause I get `list sub-command REMOVE_ITEM requires list to be present.` error under cmake 3.5.0, windows 10 with the code above.

Comment: Yes, this works under CMake 3.5.0.  Probably given your error message, you've either "dereferenced" your list (e.g. done `list(REMOVE_ITEM ${sources} ...)` rather than `list(REMOVE_ITEM sources ...)`), or your list is empty.