# Remove a source file after adding it with target_sources() in CMake

Tags: c++, c, cmake

I am using CMake 3.16.

I add my source files to my target with target_sources(). I would like later in my CMakeLists.txt to remove a source file I previously added with target_sources().

For example:

```
target_sources(my_target PRIVATE main.c abc.c def.c ghi.c)

# Later...

# Remove def.c from the previously added source files.
```

Is there a way to do this ideally without setting a custom "sources" variable and removing it from this list with list(REMOVE_ITEM ...)?

EDIT:
The context of this question is unit testing static functions in C.
My program is made of a lot of static functions that I want to unit test. To test them, I decided to include the .c file in the test files instead of the .h.

For example:
abc.c:

```c
#include "abc.h"
// several static functions defined here
```

abc.h:

```c
// some stuff
```

test_abc.c:

```c
#include "unity.h" // a unit test framework
#include "abc.c" // notice the .c instead of the .h to be able to test the static functions

// the test functions
```

By doing this, I need to remove in CMake the xxx.c file if I add the test_xxx.c file because otherwise the content of the xxx.c file will be defined 2 times and the linker will not be happy with it.

Comment: I think we are looking at a https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem so please take one step back and describe why your want to do that.

Comment: You mention using one variable. I'd rather use *two*: One "base" list, and one with the extra source. Should be easier to maintain I think. But yeah this is definitely an XY problem.

Comment: You can try as mentioned here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16449676/remove-specific-file-from-cmake-build .

Comment: @Yunnosch I edited my question to clarify the context.

Comment: @user3389943 Thanks but as I mentioned it I would like to know if there is another solution than this one because I would like to stick with target_sources(). Does it make sense to use target_sources() with a list holding the sources?

Comment: List of sources for the executable/library is reflected by [SOURCES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/prop_tgt/SOURCES.html) property of the target. You may modify this property, so list of the actual source files will be changed. Note, that in CMake "unusual" modification of the property could be performed in 3 steps: 1. Read the value of the property into the variable. 2. Change the variable (or create another one). 3. Write the property from the variable. Only standard modifications, like appending value to the list, could be performed in a single step, without the intermediate variable.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Am I taking any risk to break the generation or the build process doing this? I am just not sure it makes sense to use target_sources() with a variable holding the sources but if it is a safe and proper way then it is fine for me.

Comment: Changing `SOURCES` property shouldn't harm CMake configuration process and further building process. In fact, `target_sources` is just a convenient way for append files to this property. I find modification of the `SOURCES` property is a better way than maintaining own variable with the sources list across the directories.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the source file property [HEADER_FILE_ONLY](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_sf/HEADER_FILE_ONLY.html) to `ON` on the source file in question. See also [set_source_files_properties()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_source_files_properties.html).

Since CMake version 3.18, you can also do this if the source file belongs to a target defined in a different directory:

```
set_source_files_properties(subdir/source.c TARGET_DIRECTORY target-from-subdir PROPERTIES HEADER_FILE_ONLY ON)
```